# why an adjacency list might not be preferred for a tree?

Tags: tree

As Tree is sparse graph with no cycles, is there a reason Adjacency List is not preferred representation?
Why is linked structure used most commonly to represent tree?

Comment: I am not sure if that is totally correct. From what I read, Languages implement trees - BST - Red Black Trees as linked structures (nodes pointing to nodes) and not adjacency lists. May be if order between the siblings is important then we use linked structures otherwise we can go with adjacency list.

Comment: So in case of n-ary, advantage of hashmap (adj lists) is that we can access any node and its adj. list in o(1). When would I prefer use of pointers (node itself stores its children array)  for n-ary?

Comment: Yes, thank you. That answers my question well.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why Use Adjacency Matrices or Adjacency Lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59450195/why-use-adjacency-matrices-or-adjacency-lists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping the data for neighbors (children) in an external adjacency list versus fields in node objects is a design decision about where to put data such that is most conducive to supporting typical operations for the data structure.

[Adjacency lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) are often implemented as a hash of `node => node[]` pairs where every node points to a list or set of its neighbors (in a tree, children). This representation is much more typical of [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) than trees ([trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure) are a specific type of directed graph that are acyclic and all nodes except the root have exactly one incoming edge).

The main advantage of externalizing data in an adjacency list is ease of operating on it in aggregate or offering constant time access to any member. These properties are more important on graphs where you might, for example, run a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) starting from every node in the graph. Trees, on the other hand, use the root as a single entry point for its operations ([traversals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), insertions, removals, rotations and so forth) and nodes basically don't need to be accessed randomly except as a step in such an operation starting from the root.

Among trees, there are [binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) and n-ary trees where each node has up to `n` children. Based on the follow-up comments, you mention [BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)s and [red-black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) trees (both binary trees) as examples of using child pointers (i.e. `this.left`, `this.right`) instead of an adjacency list.

For binary trees, `node.left` and `node.right` are very explicit properties. Keeping two separate hashes for left and right children and accessing them with `leftChildren[node]` and `rightChildren[node]` is verbose, adds extra state and incurs hash lookup overhead with no obvious merit.

It gets worse for red-black trees, which are concerned with parents and other relationships, each of which would require an additional "adjacency" hash. Adjacency lists (or any list/array) is basically out of the picture for binary trees or anything with `node.left` and `node.right` properties, but still on the table for n-ary trees, for which the `node.children` property is much more akin to `tree[node]` or `children[node]`.

In addition to accessing fields, when properties are in external data structures, function headers and state in general can become more complex. Consider `def inorder(tree, root)` versus `def inorder(root)`. `tree` could be made a class member, but that doesn't change the fact that extra state needs to be passed around and managed somehow.

Another consideration is that some languages such as C have no native support for hash maps, sets or dynamic lists. It's possible to give nodes 0..n id fields and index into an array, but the pointer approach is natural in lower-level languages.

In some cases, the data in a graph or tree is so simple (say, sequential integers), that nodes can be completely eliminated in favor of a lone adjacency list or 2d array. A [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) is a good example of tree data that works very nicely as a flat structure, reinforcing the idea of picking whatever representation makes the most sense.